# Can you use a variable value as a variable name in Python

Tags: python, variables

Can you use a variable value as part of another variable name in Python.

For example, lets assume that I have a few variables named a1, a2, a3

Then can I access the variable using the value of another variable, lets say b = 2, therefore can I access a2
Something like (this is wrong but helps to explain)

```
a1 = "First"
a2 = "Second"
a3 = "Third"
b = 2
print(a%s,b)
```

This should print variable a2.

Thanks

Comment: Don't. Read https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761.

Comment: Create list a = ['first', ' second', .... ] access it  using b as index of a : a[b] or something similar using a dictionary ?